# My code is not giving output , I expected some number

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, while-loop

I am expecting some number as output from the above code,but I am not getting it out.
I am new to python but started coding with PHP.
Sorry if I go wrong some where.thanks

```
# By Websten from forums
#
# Given your birthday and the current date, calculate your age in days.
# Compensate for leap days.
# Assume that the birthday and current date are correct dates (and no time travel).
# Simply put, if you were born 1 Jan 2012 and todays date is 2 Jan 2012
# you are 1 day old.
#
# Hint
# A whole year is 365 days, 366 if a leap year.
def nextDay(year, month, day):
    """Simple version: assume every month has 30 days"""
    if day < 30:
        return year, month, day + 1
    else:
        if month == 12:
            return year + 1, 1, 1
        else:
            return year, month + 1, 1

def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    """Returns the number of days between year1/month1/day1
      and year2/month2/day2. Assumes inputs are valid dates
      in Gergorian calendar, and the first date is not after
      the second."""
    num = 0

    # YOUR CODE HERE!
    yearx = year1
    monthx = month1
    dayx = day1

    while ((year2 >= year1 ) and ( month2 >= month1 ) and ( day2 >= day1 ) ) :
         yearx,monthx,dayx = nextDay(yearx,monthx,dayx)
         num = num + 1
    num = '5'
    return num 

print daysBetweenDates(2012,9,30,2012,10,30)
```

Comment: Your program is stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: You aren't changing `year2`, `month2`, or `day2` or `year1`, `month1`, or `day`, so your while loop never terminates.

Comment: `year2 <= 2012 and month1 <= 9 and day1 <= 30` then it at somepoint month1 = 10 it should stop.Right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the line:

> while ((year2 >= year1 ) and ( month2 >= month1 ) and ( day2 >= day1 ) ) :

to:

> while ((year2 >= yearx ) and ( month2 >= monthx ) and ( day2 >= dayx ) ) :

because you are not changing the value of month1 in your code but that of monthx.

Also, I think your while loop will break when dayx is greather that day2, so your measurement will be off by 1.

Comment: thanks a lot,I got my mistake,I can't upvote as I has 1 point

Comment: No problem ;) Infinite loops are sneaky.

Comment: This will still return incorrect answer if we change the year, try : `(2012,9,30,2013,11,30)`

Answer (score 1):

I have never mastered the while statement in Python but I think that is your infinite loop it is always true that day2 > day1  etc.  So that condition remains true therefore you are stuck with num increasing

What does happen - do you get any error message?

if I were doing this I would set functions to determine

1. if the years are the same
2. if the years are the same then calculate the days between them
3. if the years are not the same calculate the number of days between the first date and the end of the year for that particular year
4. Calculate the number of days between the beginning of the year of the second date to the second date
5. Calculate the number of years difference between the end of the first year and the beginning of the second year and convert that into days

It may be clunky but it should get you home

Comment: `year2 <= 2012 and month1 <= 9 and day1 <= 30` then it at somepoint month1 = 10 it should stop.Right ?, I don't get any error.`>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>>` I get this

Comment: thanks a lot,I got my mistake,I can't upvote as I has 1 point

Comment: FYI, if you have a single space in front of the number in a list it will format better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in just one function

```
def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
##
# Your code here.
##
a1=str(month1)+'/'+str(day1)+'/'+str(year1)
date1 = datetime.strptime(a1, '%m/%d/%Y')

a2=str(month2)+'/'+str(day2)+'/'+str(year2)
date2 = datetime.strptime(a2, '%m/%d/%Y')

result= (date2 - date1).days
return result
```